# MarkLogic: Error in harmonization in MarkLogic Data Hub Content.sjs

Tags: javascript, marklogic

While running the harmonization in MarkLogic Data Hub, I found some of the records are not being harmonized. This is because of a common “invalid entity reference” error encountered in the content.sjs.

> XDMP-DOCENTITYREF: xdmp.unquote(" \n 127318\n ...") -- Invalid entity reference " " at line 20

Here is the line of code indicated in the error:

```
var results = [xdmp.unquote(xmlInfo), xdmp.unquote(xml)];
return Sequence.from(results);
```

Any tips or suggestion on how I can see the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the `&` character in some text. Look for that and replace it with `&amp;`.

The `&` character is used to escape other characters. See Wikipedia for more about how these [entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) work.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cassel, it worked! Any other character I should be on the look out?

Comment: Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, except when used for XML angle brackets. For instance: `<equation>3 &lt; 4</equation>`

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cassel!